# Default keyword in Swift parameter

Tags: ios, swift

When reading the initializer for a `NSLocalizedString` I see that some of the parameters are defaulted to a value `default`. What does the `default` keyword represent?

```
func NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String? = default, bundle: NSBundle = default, value: String = default, #comment: String) -> String
```

Comment: For future users if you come across default value of dictionary then refer this link: https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swift-tutorials/default-value-in-swift-dictionaries/

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This is not a valid Swift code, it's generated on the fly.

The `default` here means that there is some default value but the generator cannot visualize it right for you to see it. The default value is technically an inlined function, therefore it cannot be easily converted to a simple declaration.

You can see similar declarations for `assert`

```
func assert(condition: @auto_closure () -> Bool,
            _ message: StaticString = default,
                 file: StaticString = default,
                 line: UWord = default)
```

Where `file` defaults to `#file` (`__FILE__` in Swift 1.x) and `line` defaults to `#line` (`__LINE__` in Swift 1.x).

In the case of `NSLocalizedString`, the default value is `"Localizable"`, referencing the default localization file `Localizable.strings`.

Comment: Ah, okey. That's why I was not able to find anything on the default keyword. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I googled for this but landed just on non-informtive Apple pages. But when typing my question here on SO I got this useful answer immediately :-)

Comment: But why are we able to call it with all parameters then?

Comment: @Warpzit What do you mean by that? We can call it with all parameters because every default value can be overriden.

Comment: @Sulthan I read the first line: "This is not a valid Swift code, it's generated on the fly." but didn't ponder enough on the second line, but your comment was just the last thing I needed to understand it properly so thanks a lot.

Comment: @Warpzit I have the same question: "But why are we able to call it with all parameters then?"

Comment: @VitonZhang Basically the compiler does the best it can based on the info it has. In this case it just isn't good enough...

Comment: As I understand it from Hamish's comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392998/difficulties-to-assign-default-value-to-a-parameter-of-a-function/52393108#comment91731284_52392998, this is going to change in Swift 5.