# default keyword in XCTAssert

Tags: swift, swift2

XCTAssert has this definition:

> public func XCTAssert(@autoclosure expression: () -> BooleanType, _
>   message: String = default, file: String = default, line: UInt =
>   default)

Notice the last three arguments have a default value of **default**.  What does default mean? Why am I not able to use it in my own declarations?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24116621/669586 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991791/default-keyword-in-swift-parameter/24991852#24991852 . Neither is a duplicate but together they should give you the answer.

Comment: Is the default keyword reserved for XCT only? I am not able to use it in my own declarations.

Comment: It's not a keyword, see the 2nd link in the comment above.