# how to create a serial queue in swift4

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

```
DispatchQueue.init(label: , qos:  , attributes: , autoreleaseFrequency:  , target:  )
```

How to write the parameters,
I looked at the original notes for a long time，But I still can't write a serial queue

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer?