# How does `= default` parameter in Swift work?

Tags: swift

Excerpt from Swift Standard Library

```
...
///   - separator: A string to print between each item. The default is a single
///     space (`" "`).
///   - terminator: The string to print after all items have been printed. The
///     default is a newline (`"\n"`).
...
public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default)
```

How is default value for `separator` is being set to `space` and for `terminator` - `\n`?

Comment: Compare (dupe?) [Default keyword in Swift parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24991791/2976878)

Comment: `func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n")`

Answer (score 2):

This is normally not possible in swift. As you can see, this does not compile:

```
func a(_ a: String = default) {
    print(a)
}

a()
```

It's another one of those things that they do when you go to the definition of something in the standard library. It's like the "header file" of swift. :)

As you can see, the `print` method you showed does not even have a body. How is that possible? No it's not. But they can do what they want because its aim is to show you the declaration, not how it is implemented.

Comment: Not just for the standard library, it applies to all header files (Navigate > Jump to Generated Interface).