# What is "default" in swift string data: allowLossyCompression:

Tags: swift, default

I see this method

```
func data(using encoding: String.Encoding, allowLossyConversion: Bool = default) -> Data?
```

defined in the Apple docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1690799-data
; but what does this mean?

```
allowLossyConversion: Bool = default
```

I know it means there is a parameter called `allowLossyCompression` which may be omitted as it is assigned a default value. But what does "default" mean there? **Is it **true** or **false**?**  And how would I know? (I know I can guess its false; but, my question is if something is missing from the docs or the word **default** means something and is somehow defined and configurable for my project.

A related question, [Default keyword in Swift parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991791/default-keyword-in-swift-parameter), also does not answer this question. Specifically, **Is it **true** or **false**?**. I know we can *guess* it is false as that is the default in most languages; but, is there no way to know while writing code in xCode (short of run-time debugging?).

There must be a way to know what the "default" and **Is it **true** or **false**?**

Comment: Not really. The question is more exact here and the answer there is not complete either. I suspect there is some config space for whether this is true or false; but do not know yet. Thanks.